# How to permanently set vault token and url remote server in macos

Tags: mac-osx, vault, variables

On Linux I'm setting vault variables to /etc/environment next:

```
export VAULT_URL='https://some-remote-server.org:8200/'
export VAULT_TOKEN='SoMeToKeN'
```

But when I'm typeing this in macos, after `$> vault status` I'm getting
`Error checking seal status: Get "https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused`

What am I doing wrong and how to do it right to get remote access to the vault?

Answer (score 1):

The file `/etc/environment` is more of a configuration file than a script. Just tell it the variables you want to be set without the `export` keyword:

```
VAULT_URL='https://some-remote-server.org:8200/'
VAULT_TOKEN='SoMeToKeN'
```